# ValueError exception in python3?

Tags: python, valueerror

I'm a python beginner and i was making a simple number guessing game, but every time i accidently type in a letter or a symbol instead of a number, i get the ValueError. How do I pass this error throughout the entire program? i know the code is messy, and I'm sorry for that but I'm just trying to have some fun with it.

```
import random
tries = 15
money = 0
cheat = 0
run = True
random_number = random.randint(1, 20)

while run:
    if cheat >= 1:
        print(random_number)
        cheat -= 1

    guess = input("Pick a number from 1-20! You have " + str(tries) + " tries")
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess == random_number:
        money += 5
        print("You got it right! You got it with " + str(tries) + " tries left", "your balance is", + money)
        again = input("Play again? yes/no")
        if again == "yes":
            random_number = random.randint(1, 20)
        else:
            break

        #store system
        shop = input("Would you like to access the shop? yes/no")
        if shop == "yes":
            try_cost = 10
            cheat_cost = 20

            #if player has enough money
            buy_try = input("Would you like to purchase more tries? price is 10 dollars for 5 tries. yes/no")
            if buy_try == "yes" and money >= 10:
                tries += 5
                money -= 10
                print("You have", tries, "tries", "and", money, "money", "and", cheat, "cheats")

            buy_cheat = input("Would you like to purchase a cheat? price is 20 dollars for 2 cheats")
            if buy_cheat == "yes" and money >= 20:
                cheat += 2
                money -= 20
                print("You have", tries, "tries", "and", money, "money", "and", cheat, "cheats")

            # if player doesn't have enough money
            elif buy_try == "yes" and money != 10:
                print("You don't have enough for that, you have", money, "dollars")
            elif buy_cheat == "yes" and money != 20:
                print("You don't have enough for that, you have", money, "dollars")

    elif guess > random_number:
        print("Try a little lower!")
        tries -= 1
    elif guess < random_number:
        print("Try a little higher!")
        tries -= 1
    if tries == 0:
        print("you ran out of tries!")
        run = False
```

Pick a number from 1-20! You have 15 triess
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bashr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 15, in 
guess = int(guess)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: oh crap I'm sorry. I had thought I included that.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, use a `try` and `except` clause.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to access that error inside this whole file then you can use global variable or you can use class concept

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way to solve that is a while: while the input Is not a digit ask again the input.
So, in your case, every time you use the input function you should use something likes this:

```
guess = input("Pick a number from 1-20! You have " + str(tries) + " tries")
while not guess.isdigit():
    print("the input Is not a digit, please retry")
    guess = input("Pick a number from 1-20! You have...")
```

Or you can use you can use try and except

Comment: Hi, Ive tried both try and except, and a while loop, but everytime I do,  it either "undeclares" the guess variable? I'm not sure if thats the right word, but it wont recognize it anymore. The while statement does the same thing. I think its because I didnt use and def functions, kinda sucks because I dont wanna do the whole thing again

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand. I copy/pasted your code and added the while I suggested before. I think it works: 

`while run:
    if cheat >= 1:
        print(random_number)
        cheat -= 1

    guess = input("Pick a number from 1-20! You have " + str(tries) + " tries")
    while not guess.isdigit():
        print("the input Is not a digit, please retry")
        guess = input("Pick a number from 1-20! You have...")
    guess = int(guess)`